# JavaScript - Splitting a functionalized variable in two

Tags: javascript, function, variables, bots, javascript-objects

This question is ideally for anyone mostly knowledgeable about JavaScript and sufficiently familiar with the Myers-Briggs Type Indicator/personality framework. Assuming absence of the latter, what I wish to do with the code below is create two "bots" each with distinct and randomly-generated "personality types". Personality types in this case will consist of four letters (e.g., INTJ; ESFP). Each type has four out of a total of eight MBTI "preferences"--all possible such preferences include E, I, S, N, T, F, J, and P.

Here is the relevant part of my program:

```
var playerbot, playerbot_SN, playerbot_TF, playerbot_EI, playerbot_JP

//arrays of MBTI preferences and types, respectively
MBTIprefs = ["F", "T", "I", "E", "S", "N", "P", "J"]
MBTItypes = ["ESTJ", "INFP", "ISTJ", "ENFP", "INTJ", "ESFP", "ISFJ", "ESTP",
"ISFP", "INTP", "INFJ", "ENFJ", "ENTJ", "ENTP", "ISTP", "ESFJ"]

//MBTI preference assessments
var assessCount = 0

for (assessCount = 1; asssessCount <= 2; ++assessCount) 
{
    function assessMBTIprefs(MBTIprefs, MBTItypes) 
    {
        MBTI_ques = ["MBTI_SN_q", "MBTI_TF_q", "MBTI_EI_q", "MBTI_JP_q"]
        MBTI_ques[0] = "Are you more realistic or speculative?"
        MBTI_SN_answs = ["realistic", "speculative"]
        function pickRandomProperty(MBTI_SN_answs) 
        {
            var playerbot_SN_ans;
            var count = 0;
            for (var prop in MBTI_SN_answs)
                if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
                playerbot_SN_ans = prop;
            return playerbot_SN_ans;
        }
        if playerbot_SN_ans == MBTI_TF_answs[0]
            playerbot_SN = MBTIprefs[4]
        else if playerbot_SN_ans == MBTI_TF_answs[1]
            playerbot_SN = MBTIprefs[5]

        MBTI_ques[1] = "Are you more impressed by principles or emotions?"
        MBTI_TF_answs = ["principles", "emotions"]
        function pickRandomProperty(MBTI_TF_answs) 
        {
            var playerbot_TF_ans;
            var count = 0;
            for (var prop in MBTI_TF_answs)
                if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
                playerbot_TF_ans = prop;
            return playerbot_TF_ans;
        }
        if playerbot_TF_ans == MBTI_TF_answs[0]
            playerbot_TF = MBTIprefs[1]
        else if playerbot_TF_ans == MBTI_TF_answs[1]
            playerbot_TF = MBTIprefs[0]

        MBTI_ques[2] = "Do you prefer to have many friends with brief contact or a few friends with more lengthy contact?"
        MBTI_EI_answs = ["many friends with brief contact", "a few friends with more lengthy contact"]
        function pickRandomProperty(MBTI_EI_answs) 
        {
            var playerbot_EI_ans;
            var count = 0;
            for (var prop in MBTI_EI_answs)
                if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
                playerbot_EI_ans = prop;
            return playerbot_EI_ans;
        }
        if playerbot_EI_ans == MBTI_EI_answs[0]
            playerbot_EI = MBTIprefs[3]
        else if playerbot_EI_ans == MBTI_EI_answs[1]
            playerbot_EI = MBTIprefs[2]

        MBTI_ques[3] = "Should one usually let events occur by careful selection and choice or randomly and by chance?"
        MBTI_JP_answs = ["careful selection and choice", "randomly and by chance"]
        function pickRandomProperty(MBTI_JP_answs) 
        {
            var playerbot_JP_ans;
            var count = 0;
            for (var prop in MBTI_JP_answs)
                if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
                playerbot_JP_ans = prop;
            return playerbot_JP_ans;
        }
        if playerbot_JP_ans == MBTI_JP_answs[0]
            playerbot_JP = MBTIprefs[7]
        else if playerbot_JP_ans == MBTI_JP_answs[1]
            playerbot_JP = MBTIprefs[6]
    }

    function assessMBTItypes(assessMBTIprefs, MBTItypes) 
    {
        if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[0]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[1]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[7]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[2]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[15]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[12]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[5]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[13]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[14]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[9]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[1] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[4]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[10]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[8]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[4] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[2] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[7]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[6]
        else if playerbot_SN == MBTIprefs[5] && playerbot_TF == MBTIprefs[0] 
            && playerbot_EI == MBTIprefs[3] && playerbot_JP == MBTIprefs[6]
                playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[3]
        else playerbot_MBTI = MBTItypes[11]
    }
    return playerbot_MBTI
}
```

The umbrella "for" loop is designed to run twice, meaning that each of its functions (including both assessMBTIprefs and assessMBTItypes) would as well.

**Is there a way to basically split playerbot_MBTI from what I have above into two new vars--say, into playerbot1_MBTI and playerbot2_MBTI?**

I could just ditch the loop and duplicate assessMBTIprefs and assessMBTItypes; this way, playerbot1 and playerbot2 would each have their own functions that run separately. But I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient way that would build minimally on what I already have...

Comment: Are you sure your code runs? It looks like you just have two function declarations inside of your for loop, but you are not actually calling those functions ever.

Comment: please add a small example what you want with "*Splitting a functionalized variable in two*".

Comment: please remove 4 declarations of a function with the same body - "pickRandomProperty" - with a single function, rename the argument to "answ" or something, rename the return variable to "ans" or something, instead of function declarations please use function calls like: `var playerbot_SN_ans = pickRandomProperty(MBTI_SN_answs)`

Comment: This is... a ridiculously large amount of code to generate a random 4-bit [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array). Why not generate a random number between 0 and 0b1111, and when you need the individual preferences, `prefNS = (type & 0b0100) ? 'N' : 'S';`?

Comment: 1) The *fundamental* problem is writing the same code over and over when there can easily be one with data passed in instead of hard coding for each playerbot.  2) Make an object to hold all data for a single personality type, then there is only one array. Not multiple arrays each with only one piece of personality type data. This will significantly simplify your code no matter how you write it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, all. I've decided to go with a simpler strategy (random designation of MBTI types to two players) and combine it with an existing program for the second portion of what I need ("prisoner's dilemma" game). Mostly, I've learned to simplify my coding from feedback to this post.